# Fix git repo that mimics bare repository structure but is not

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone, git-bare, svn2git

After converting my SVN repository to a Git repository, I was left with a folder with all the contents that would normally be in a `.git` folder in the top level directory e.g.

```
Repo (top level directory)

 - branches folder
 - hooks folder
 - info folder
 - logs folder
 - objects folder
 - refs folder
 - config
 - description
 - HEAD
 - index
```

However, there was no `.git` directory. But, when I checked the history with `git log`, it showed the recent commits, and there are tags etc that have been generated. Therefore, the files are in the Git repo. The Git repo is not bare, which is confirmed by looking in the git config where it says `bare = false`.

I then initialised a git folder with `git init`, emptied its contents and moved everything in the Repo top level directory into that new `.git` folder.

When I push the whole repo to a remote repo, it just gets pushed as a "commit". When I inspect what I have pushed in Gitlab, I can see the files in the commit, but, not in the normal sense which has a directory structure etc.

How can I fix this?